# Angular 2 mdAutocomplete 2 way data binding

Tags: angular, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I'm trying to create Angular 2 MdAutocomplete with custom object data and having trouble with getting and setting object data. It looks good with filtering and displaying but not binding data, it's not setting item on edit form and not getting item while saving form. Here is my template and code:

```
**HTML:**
 *<md-input-container>
   <input type="text" required placeholder="Store" mdInput [formControl]="storeControl" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [value]="card.store.name">
   <md-hint *ngIf="card.store == null || card.store.id == 0" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}"> Store is required </md-hint>
 </md-input-container>
 <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" name="store" [(ngModel)]="card.store" [displayWith]="displayFn" ngDefaultControl>
   <md-option *ngFor="let store of filteredStores | async" [value]="store">
     {{ store?.name }}
   </md-option>
 </md-autocomplete>*

**TS**

  *private stores: Store[];
  filteredStores: Observable<Store[]>;
  private card:Card = <Card> {
  store: new Store(0,'',''),
  };
  storeControl = new FormControl();
  ngOnInit() {
    this.storeService.getStores().subscribe(result => {
      this.stores = result.items;
    });
    this.filteredStores = this.storeControl.valueChanges
      .startWith(null)
      .map(name => name ? this.filter(name) : this.stores);
  }
  filter(name: string): Store[] {
    return this.stores.filter(store => new RegExp(name, 'gi').test(store.name));
  }
  displayFn(store: Store): string {
    if (store != null) {
      this.card.store = store;
    }
    return store ? store.name : '';
  }*

Object Item: Store(id, name, description)
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understading the `[formControl]` directive is part of ReactiveForms and the `ngModel` is Angular way to do it all in the framework. So since you are mixin the both ways angular work with forms for the autocomplete input you would have to do it manually like in the reactive way.

So it would be something like:

```
this.storeControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {this.store.card.name = value})
```

To make a binding

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

```
options: store[] = [];
```

**Provide below filterOptions in constructor**

```
constructor(private storeService: StoreService) { 
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
        .startWith(null)
        .map(store=> store&& typeof store=== 'object' ? store.name: store)
        .map(name=> name? this.filter(name) : this.options.slice());
}
```